# Passing a parameter to my Knockout ViewModel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC site that uses Knockout JS.  Basically, the MVC handles routing to a few different pages, and each page has a viewmodel.

One of the pages requires a parameter to filter the data. The code for the MVC Controller for that page is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Transactions(int policyId)
{
    ViewData["policyId"] = policyId;
    return View();
}
```

The View for that page includes a hidden field.

> `<input type="hidden" name="hldPolicy" value="@ViewData["policyId"]">`

Then after the html for the page,

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myBundle")
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var policyId = $('#hldPolicy').val();
            var transactionViewModel = new TransactionViewModel(policyId);
            ko.applyBindings(transactionViewModel);
        });

    </script>
}
```

The problem is this doesn't work because the hidden field is undefined when the script runs. That doesn't make sense to me as I thought that was what the $(document).ready was protecting against. What am I doing wrong here?  And is there a better way to pass a parameter from the URL params into the viewmodel?

Comment: try using document.ready at the bottom of ur page where body end's

Comment: where is the definition of `TransactionViewModel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it like this. Here you dont actually have to pass the parameter instead define a function which will be called on viewmodel initialization and get the data according to your requirements.

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myBundle")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TransactionViewModel(){
            var self = this
            self.SomeProperty = ko.observable()

            self.LoadData = function(){
                var policyId = $('#hldPolicy').val();
                self.SomeProperty(policyId)
            }
            self.LoadData()
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new TransactionViewModel());
        });
    </script>
}
```

When knockout model will be initialized it will call `self.LoadData()` automatically.

EDIT

I found you are missing id attribute at your input

```
<input type="hidden" id="hldPolicy" name="hldPolicy" value="@ViewData["policyId"]">
```

Now it should work properly.

EDIT:

You can also do it like this

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myBundle")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TransactionViewModel(policyId){
            var self = this
            self.SomeProperty = ko.observable()

            self.LoadData = function(policyId){
                self.SomeProperty(policyId)
            }
            self.LoadData(policyId);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var policyId = $('#hldPolicy').val();
            ko.applyBindings(new TransactionViewModel(policyId));
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This is a bit easier to debug but I'm still getting $('#hldPolicy').val() as undefined. But when I look at the page source, it has '<input type="hidden" name="hldPolicy" value="86">'